# Unusual line breaks in equation

Tags: equations

I've got the following code, but I dont know why it creates line breaks in the equation

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item My Equation 
  \begin{equation}
      P$\wedge$S \equiv \emph{False} $\implies$ L : lineBreaks
  \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
```

Output:

[image: Unwanted line breaks]

Comment: There should be no `$` in an `equation` environment. And no ``\\`` either. Please, state precisely what's the output you're expecting.

Comment: @egreg Oh!, I need to define escape key for the equation?

Comment: What you put in an `equation` is already "between `$`". And if you want to split it between different lines you should look at `amsmath`'s environments (`align`, `gather`, `split`, `multline`,... ).

Comment: @egreg and Manuael thanks for the comments and tips! I added the working version.

Comment: @Manuel thanks for pointing out!, just realised this fact! :P

Answer (score 2):

The equation should be written like this:

```
\begin{equation}
     P \wedge S \equiv \textit{False}   \implies  L : \textit{lineBreaks}
\end{equation}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I would make the equation read as follows: `P\wedge S \equiv \textit{False} \implies L : \textit{lineBreaks}`. That way, you'll get better kerning of the letters in "False" and "lineBreaks".